# Por que quando eu informo "1.93" dá erro ao converter para inteiro?

Tags: python, conversão-de-tipo, int

```
print('Calculadora de IMC')
peso = input('Insira o seu peso (em kg): ')
altura = input('Insira sua altura (em metros): ')

IMC = int(peso) / int(altura)**2
```

Quando coloco o valor da altura como "1.93" aparece um erro falando assim:

```
    IMC = int(peso) / int(altura)**2
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.93'
```

Tem como deixar o código de jeito que eu possa colocar os valores quebrados?

Comment: Sim. O valor "1.93" não é um valor inteiro válido, então é esperado que desse o erro citado.

Comment: como posso escrever para poder colocar este valor quebrado?

Comment: Não tratar ele como inteiro... talvez como `float`.

Comment: @orbitB374 Use o tipo `float`.

Comment: muito obrigado gente :)
sou novo em python, então to aprendendo tudo ainda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como pode ver na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int):

> **class int([x])** / **class int(x, base=10)**
>
> *Return an integer object constructed from a number or string `x`, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If `x` defines `__int__()`, `int(x)` returns `x.__int__()`. If `x` defines `__trunc__()`, it returns `x.__trunc__()`. For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.*
>
> *If `x` is not a number or if base is given, then `x` must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base.*

O parâmetro pode ser um número ou uma string. Se o parâmetro implementar o método `__trunc__()`, será retornado o valor `x.__trunc__()`, que é o caso quando você passa um número com ponto flutuante.

Se o parâmetro define `__int__()` então será retornado `x.__int__()`.

Se o parâmetro for do tipo string, bytes ou bytearray, então será feito a conversão conforme a base informada, que por padrão é 10, base decimal, que usamos no dia-a-dia. Ao passar um valor como `'1.93'`, devida a presença das aspas, isso será uma string e, portanto, será tentada a conversão dessa string para inteiro na base 10. Como o valor `1.93` é inválido na base 10 (pois o caractere `.` não existe na base 10), dá o erro citado.

Mas isso foi só para explicar o porquê do erro, pois a solução é mais simples que isso, dado que é um erro de lógica mesmo, visto que é esperada uma entrada decimal e está sendo tratada como inteira. Basta. então, tratá-la devidamente como decimal. Para isso, uma das formas de fazer é usando `float`.

Uma alternativa é utilizar a biblioteca `decimal`, nativa do Python.

Comment: hmmm entendi, caramba você explicou muito bem
obrigado amigo, de verdade, consegui montar a calculadora aqui certinho. tenha um bom dia :D

Comment: @orbitB374 não esqueça de sinalizar como resposta favorita se esta foi a melhor solução pra você.

Comment: @orbitB374 E antes de mais nada, por favor faça o **[tour]**.